# FW/1 How to return ajax data without view?

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

I have the following function that returns `rc.employee`. I am calling this function `checkempid` from the index page of a model. I am triggering this to run `onblur`. I only want the data to come back, but FW1 seems to be rendering the entire page again inside my div. How can I only return the data and not the entire page/view?

```
public any function checkempid(struct rc = {}) {
    var employeeid = rc.employeeid;
    rc.employee = variables.activeidentificationService.checkempid(employeeid);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using sending a JSON response and use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20511721/1479535).

In your case since you are not returning a plain text you can use the following.

```
public any function checkempid(struct rc = {}) {
    var employeeid = rc.employeeid;
    rc.employee = variables.activeidentificationService.checkempid(employeeid);
    variables.fw.renderData( "text", rc.employee);
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.